# How do I go about removing all my wifi tools in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, wifi

My wifi setup is messed up and I keep disconnecting.  I want to start from scratch, so I need to know how to thoroughly remove all my wifi tools.  I don't want to forget some errant config file and have my new setup skewed.

What's the best way to get a listing of my wifi programs and services?

Comment: I would suggest some command-line troubleshooting before clearing it all. Have a look here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup, you might come across interesting errors in your terminal ;)

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I've worked on that page for a couple of days now and so far nothing has helped.